# Finding data from database which has been clicked 12 hours ago in Laravel

Tags: laravel

This is my `advertisements` table:

[image: advertisements table]

And this is my `works` table:

[image: works table]

I want to find data from the `advertisements` table which has been clicked 12 hours ago, on recorded from `works` table, by the `add_id` column.

**Work Model:**

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Work extends Model
{

}
```

**Advertisement Model:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Advertisement extends Model
{
    //
}
```

**Controller:**

```
 public function myadd()
 {
     $clicked_add = Work::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDay())->get();
     $adds = Advertisement::orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(5)->get();
     return View::make('pages.add', compact("adds","clicked_add"));
 }
```

Comment: Do you have model on each table?

Comment: Can you show us what did you try?

Comment: sorry for short, i edited my problem. thank you

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to set belongsTo advertisments relationship on works model,than you can eagerly load the works object with advertisement.
For -i.e-: Your relationship function name is advertisements on works model you can call like this.

```
$works=Works::with(['advertisements'=>function($query){
     $query->where('update_time','=',\Carbon\Carbon new carbon()->subHours(12))
}])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the advertisement that has been click in the past 12 hours.

(I'll assumed that work.created_at will be generate once the user clicked your advertisement)

Try this

```
$works = Advertisement ::leftJoin('works ', 'works.add_id','=','advertisement.id')
                      ->select('advertisement.*')
                      ->where('works.created_at','>=',\Carbon\Carbon::now()->subHours(12))
                      ->get();
```